Autopep8 vscode not ordering imports correctly
I use an autopep8 formatter .
When I optimize imports, packages from rest_framework are now ordered ta the end.
Up until a few days ago, ‘rest_framework’ packages used to be on top along with other inbuilt Python packages like OS, Pandas etc.
VScode version:
Version: 1.91.1
Date: 2024-07-09T22:08:12.169Z
Electron: 29.4.0
ElectronBuildId: 9728852
Chromium: 122.0.6261.156
Node.js: 20.9.0
V8: 12.2.281.27-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.15.0-113-generic
Autopep8 version - v2024.0.0

I had following folder structure
MainFolder/django_folder 

I was opening MainFolder in workspace but wanted all my imports to use django_folder as parent folder.
So whenever I would import something - I had to manually remove Mainfolder from import path.
Solution
was to open django_folder directly in workspace . This way my imports automatically considered django_folder as parent folder instead of using Mainfolder as parent folder in import statements.
This automatically resolved import issue and now django and rest_framework
is correctly ordered on top of all custom imports.
It had nothing to do with vscode or autopep8 version.
